# Weighted averages in harmonic functions.

Tags: harmonic-functions

Is it the case that for a harmonic function on a graph any value of the interior point is the weighted average of the boundary points? I know that for a harmonic function each point is the weighted average of its adjacent neighbors, but can you extend that to the boundary points?

Comment: What does this have to do with harmonic functions? Also, there is a lot of definition missing here - in what context are you using "interior points" and "boundary points?"

Answer (score 2):

The answer is *yes* if your graph $G$ is finite (as it appears to be from your post). Let $b_1,\dots,b_m$ be the boundary vertices. For each $k\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ there is a unique harmonic function $u_k$ on $G$ such that $u_k(b_k)=1$ and $u_k(b_j)=0$ for $j\ne k$. (This is just the existence/uniqueness for the Dirichlet problem.) Since $0\le u_k\le 1$ on the boundary, we have $0\le u_k\le 1$ on the entire graph. Also, the function $u_1+\dots+u_m$ is equal to $1$ at every boundary point, and therefore is identically equal to $1$.

Suppose that $u$ is a harmonic function on $G$. Then the equality
$$u(x) = \sum_{j=1}^m u(b_j) u_j(x)\tag1$$
holds for all $x$ on the boundary (by construction), and therefore for all $x\in G$ (by the uniqueness for the Dirichlet problem, essentially the maximum principle). The formula (1) represents $u(x)$ as the weighted average of boundary values $u(b_j)$, the weights being $u_j(x)$. Recall that $u_j(x)$ are nonnegative and add up to $1$, so they are indeed weights.

---

Some additional remarks.

One key term in this subject is *harmonic measure*. For each interior point  $x$ the harmonic measure $\omega_x$ gives weights $u_j(x)$ to boundary points $b_j$. This is a probability measure supported on the boundary. In terms of this measure, (1) can be written as 
$$u(x) = \int_{\partial G} u \, d\omega_x\tag2$$
bringing notation in alignment with the [harmonic measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_measure) for the classical Laplace equation. One can then ask whether (2) holds on infinite graphs. There are simple counterexamples, such as the function $u(n)=n$ on the graph with vertices $0,1,2,3,4,\dots$ where adjacent integers are connected. But if $u$ is assumed to be bounded, then positive results are possible. Or, one can introduce "boundary at infinity" of the graph and re-interpret (2) in terms of a measure on that ideal boundary.

Another key term is *random walk*. Consider random walk $x_n$ on the graph that starts at $x_0=x$ and stops upon reaching a boundary point. By harmonicity, the value $u(x)$ is equal to the expectation of $u(x_n)$ for any $n$. If (i) the walk reaches boundary almost surely, and (ii) $u$ is reasonable (say, bounded), then we can pass to the limit $n\to\infty$ and obtain (2). For example, if the graph is square grid on half-plane $\{(m,n):m,n\in\mathbb Z, n\ge 0\}$ then $\omega_x$ is distributed along the boundary $\{(m,0):m\in\mathbb Z\}$.